# TabContainer goes Invisible when I make child tab visible = false

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been struggling with this for a day.  Not finding any others with my exact situation, so I figured I'd post and answer with what worked for me.

Environment: Asp.net 4.0 - AjaxControlToolkit v.7.1213.0

Problem:  I have a TabContainer with 3 tabs, and based on a database value, I will make the 2nd tab invisible or not.  My problem is that when I make that second tab invisible it makes the entire tabContainer invisible.  When I inspect source, I can see the control is rendered on the page (tested in Firefox And Chrome), but there's now a style tag (visibility:hidden) that is coming from somewhere NOT in my code (master page, child page, style.css, c# codebehind files, etc), as far as I can tell.  I have yet to find an explanation for this errant style tag.  I'm not an ASP.net master, so it could be some idiosyncracy with my code, but it's also possible that this is a bug with AjaxControltoolkit.

I'll answer this with the workaround that is currently working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

Since I only need to remove / hide this from my users, I am able to use the Tabcontainer.Remove method.  When using this method, my tabContainer no longer disappears after postback when it contains an invisible tab.

I replaced:

```
if(x.value == true)
```

tabpanel1.Visible == false;

with:

```
if(x.value == true)
```

tabContainer1.Tabs.Remove(tabpanel1);